# What is the best way to improve wordpress performance?

Tags: html, performance

I am trying to get my client's site performance score above 80 in `http://tools.pingdom.com/`. I have installed GZIP compression, Lazyload, WP Super Cache and moved my js scripts to the footer:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------#
// Begin Custom Scripting to Move JavaScript from the Head to the Footer

function remove_head_scripts() { 
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts'); 
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9); 
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);

add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_head_scripts' );

// END Custom Scripting to Move JavaScript
```

I am still not scoring above 77%. Since a lot of the images are added via admin, I am unable to control their size. Another frustrating thing how the CSS files and themes are that they are kept separately and uncompressed. I have had to manually minify each of the css files as a result of their different locations and priority.Unfortunately I am unable to share my website's URL but if there is anything I can do to improve speed?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately I am unable to share my website's URL but if there is
>   anything I can do to improve speed?

You can try WP Total Cache, it contains a tool to minify Javascript and CSS, also to remove white space inside your Code. The most important ist to see if you are using correctly your image sizes, take a look into the output and maybe add some new sizes for them within your theme functions like `add_image_size( 'mini', 50, 50, true );` (50px X 50px). Please keep in mind that you have to add these sizes also to your theme as output and at least use a tool to generate your thumbnails and images new.

Comment: Hi I am not sure I understand the image answer. I have WP Total Cache installed but I cannot find any minifying tools in the settings page. Also, in terms of adding image sizes, to which images does this apply? The stuff added via the admin section or the website's current set-up?